# ktor how to wrap calls in try-catch

Tags: ktor

I find myself repeating many lines of code in every ktor endpoint, especially the series of `catch` blocks as shown in the following example code containing two different `get` calls.

ktor plugins do not solve the problem because the call cannot be wrapped by a single block of code. There are separate calls for the call and its response so the `try-catch` cannot work.

There must be some reasonable way to do this in ktor. Please advise!

```
    get("/num") {
        val em = emf.createEntityManager()
        try {
            em.transaction.begin(); val tx = em.find(Tx::class.java, 0).v
            Num(tx = tx, v = (0..< 100).random()).also {
                em.persist(it)
                em.transaction.commit()
                call.respond(it)
            }
        } catch (e: EntityExistsException) {
            call.respondText("exception: $e", status= HttpStatusCode.BadGateway)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            call.respondText("exception", status= HttpStatusCode.BadGateway)
            Logger.getAnonymousLogger().log(Level.SEVERE, e.stackTraceToString())
        } finally {
            em.transaction.takeIf { it.isActive }?.let {
                Logger.getAnonymousLogger().log(Level.SEVERE, "rollback")
                it.rollback()
            }
        }
    }
    get("/sum") {
        val em = emf.createEntityManager()
        try {
            em.transaction.begin(); val tx_min = em.find(TxMin::class.java, 0).v
            val last_sum = em.createNamedQuery("Sum.last", Sum::class.java).resultList.firstOrNull() ?: Sum(tx=tx_min, v=0).also { em.persist(it) }
            em.createNamedQuery("Num.sum_from_to", Long::class.java).setParameter("tx_from", last_sum.tx).setParameter("tx_to", tx_min).resultList.firstOrNull()?.let {
                Sum(tx=tx_min, v=it + last_sum.v).also {
                    em.persist(it)
                    em.transaction.commit()
                    call.respond(it)
                }
            } ?: run {
                em.transaction.commit()
                call.respond(last_sum)
            }
        } catch (e: EntityExistsException) {
            call.respondText("exception: $e", status= HttpStatusCode.BadGateway)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            call.respondText("exception", status= HttpStatusCode.BadGateway)
            Logger.getAnonymousLogger().log(Level.SEVERE, e.stackTraceToString())
        } finally {
            em.transaction.takeIf { it.isActive }?.let {
                Logger.getAnonymousLogger().log(Level.SEVERE, "rollback")
                it.rollback()
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not keep the business logic in service layer?

Comment: @Anandakrishnan i don't understand these terms .. only code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added couple of test routes and I'm calling a function `handle` that accepts the current `ApplicationCall` context, execute the block of code and throw exception if needed.

```
fun Route.test1() {
        get("test1") {
            handle(call) {
                val age = call.request.queryParameters["age"]
                return@handle "You're age is $age"
            }
        }
    }

fun Route.test2() {
    get("test2") {
        handle(call) {
            val name = call.request.queryParameters["name"]
            return@handle "You're name is $name"
        }
    }
}
```

The `handle` function that takes the block of code and execute it.

```
suspend fun handle(call: ApplicationCall, block: () -> Any) {
        try {
            val result = block()
            call.respond(HttpStatusCode.OK, result)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            call.respond(HttpStatusCode.BadGateway)
        } finally {
            // do whatever
        }
    }
```

Comment: accepted; i wish there were a ktor solution like a plugin that could do this without having to add an extra line in every route handler

Answer (score 1):

[Ktor status pages](https://ktor.io/docs/status-pages.html) are exactly what you are looking for.

With them you can define how you want to handle each exception without repeating yourself.

```
install(StatusPages) {
    exception<Throwable> { call, cause ->
        if(cause is AuthorizationException) {
            call.respondText(text = "403: $cause" , status = HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
        } else {
            call.respondText(text = "500: $cause" , status = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
        }
    }
}
```